# Linear regression, reversing it back then.

Tags: statistics, logic

Need's formatting, editing will take some time.

Comment: "...using those slopes and intercept i want my original points." I might have misunderstood your question, but you are aware that it is not possible to tell which two numbers were used to get to the number 4. Was it 1+3 or 2+2?

Comment: Could you explicit the problem ? To me, it looks like optimization under constraints $a+b x_i>0$